# Java EE Singleton Injection by Reflection

Tags: java, singleton, cdi, wildfly

Java EE gives me a ( just another) headache (Wildfly 8+):

At first, imagine some Singleton POJO where the used instance is set up by some property:

**Java SE Singleton**

```
public class Singleton
{
    private Singleton instance
    public Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            try
            {
                String className = System.getProperty("singletonClass");
                instance = Class.forName(className).getInstance();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            ...
            }
        }
    return instance;
    }
}
```

You may depate that this approach is bad design. But it is the way our singleton instances are "configured".

Now i was confronted with this approch in the Java EE World. I made it work but it's just bloat ugly annotation-hell-code - besides that i am not really familiar with Java EE it might be that there are easier ways:

**ProjectManager (should be abstract)**

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class ProjectManager
{
...
}
```

**ProjectManager implementation**

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class DefaultProjectManager extends ProjectManager
{
}
```

**Producer Annotation**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD
})
public @interface DynamicProjectManager
{

}
```

**Producer**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProjectManagerProducer implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance<ProjectManager> projectManagers;

    @Produces
    @DynamicProjectManager
    private ProjectManager createProjectManager()
    {
        String clazz = System.getProperty("projectManagerType","DefaultProjectManager");
        try
        {
            return projectManagers.select((Class<ProjectManager>) Class.forName(clazz)).get();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return projectManagers.select(DefaultProjectManager.class).get();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is in another Bean:

```
@Inject
@DynamicProjectManager
private ProjectManager projectManager;
```

This works! But i see many things that don't let me sleep well at night. Currently i am not using other Frameworks (Spring or similar). So here are my questions:

1. Is there an easier way in Java EE to support Singletons(or other EJBs) where the runtime class of that singleton is not known at compile time?
2. If not: Is it possible to just Inject the Singleton Instance without additional @DynamicProjectManager Annotation?
3. Is it possible to make ProjectManager abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple, and don't mix EJB with CDI unless you absolutely need to. The following should do:

```
public interface ProjectManager {
    // add some method signatures
}


@ApplicationScoped
public class DefaultProjectManager implements ProjectManager {
    // add implementations
}

public class ProjectManagerClient {

    @Inject
    private ProjectManager projectManager;

    // work with injected bean
}
```

If there are multiple `ProjectManager` implementations around, you can either work with `@Alternative` or, if you really need to select the implementation dynamically *at runtime*, then use `Instance<ProjectManager>` and `select()` for a given qualifier.

Selecting by class name is a bad practice, violating loose coupling. It's better to use distinct qualifiers per implementation, or if you prefer a shared qualifier, then add a `@NonBinding` argument to your qualifier, so you can select by the value of this argument.

Comment: That was easy ;) Thanks! I struggled with the abstract class and never thought "programming to an interface" ist so hardly enforced. Making it an interface and not an abstract class solved the problem.